# Sorting a column in NSOutlineView that is bound to NSTreeController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sorting, nsoutlineview

I have an `NSOutlineView` that is bound to an `NSTreeController`.
In Interface builder, I have bound each column of `NSOutlineView` to the tree controller with the Controller key "`arrangedObjects`" and model key path as the entity attribute or a method in my entity class.

Now all other columns sort perfectly except for one special column. The special column has a model key path bound to a method that is declared in my Entity class. This method depending on some condition in my code will return either `NSString` or `NSDictionary`.
When it returns an `NSDictionary`, the delegate method:

```
- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView willDisplayCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item
```

parses the `NSDictionary` and returns a double value for that cell. Also note that the cell in this case is derived from `NSCell` and displays a progress bar.

In short, my special column will display a mix of progress bars and strings depending on the situation.

I would like to implement sorting so that all progress bars stay together and the strings are sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you will have some luck if you try setting the [table column's sort descriptor](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableColumn_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableColumn/setSortDescriptorPrototype%3a) to a descriptor you create with a comparator that looks at the objects' classes. (You could also try filling in the "Sort Key" in IB, using the "class" key, but I think this might be less likely to work...)

Answer (score 0):

Well i found a solution to this myself and just 2 minutes after posting my query :) The solution was to add a custom sort key in IB and define a method with that key name in my Entity class that returns an NSInteger. Since i want all NSDictionary objects to stay together and all NSStrings to be sorted, i return appropriate integer based on the object type. 
Note for anyone who might be stuggling with sort not working: Make sure binding for sortDescriptor is enabled in IB.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                 initWithKey:NULL
                                 ascending:YES
                                 selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] autorelease];
[[myOutlineView tableColumnWithIdentifier:@"Name"]setSortDescriptorPrototype:sorter];
```